# PyQt5 print widget to pdf but have text be selectable

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making an app using PyQt5. The app shows some data with text in a nice layout.

I have figures out how to save my QWidget to an image file, and the resolution is nice.

I would like to be able to save the widget as a pdf. I have tried doing this, and the result is again nice, but really no different from the image. I would like people to be able to copy and paste some of the text (like url addresses) that are in the widget after saving it. But i'd also like the layout to stay as it is.

First question: is this possible?
Second question: what is a good strategy/how does it work in Qt (preferably PyQt)

here is my code for printing to pdf using the QPixmap derived from the widget (but i know this is not what I need for the text)

```
def savepixmap_to_pdf(pixmap, name):
    from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
    widget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    widget.setPixmap(pixmap)

    printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.HighResolution)
    printer.setOutputFileName(name)
    printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setPageMargins(1, 1, 1, 1, QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.Inch)
    printer.setFullPage(False)
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)

    xscale = printer.pageRect().width() / (widget.width())
    yscale = printer.pageRect().height() / (widget.height())
    scale = min(xscale, yscale)
    painter.translate(printer.paperRect().center())
    painter.scale(scale, scale)
    painter.translate(-widget.width() / 2, -widget.height() / 2)
    widget.render(painter)
    painter.end()
```

Comment: You need to show the complete code for actual widget you are trying to save.

Comment: The widget has QLabels. some with pixmap images and others that are only text. Assume a widget with 2 QLabels, one is text and one is graph image.